# How to prevent empty list errors in in clause in sql?

Tags: sql, database, scala, anorm

One common problem we have in our codebase is that people forget to check if a list is empty before using it in an `in` clause.

For example (in Scala with Anorm):

```
def exists(element: String, list: List[String]): Boolean =
  SQL("select {element} in {list} as result")
    .on('element -> element, 'list -> list)
    .as(SqlParser.bool("result").single)
```

This code works perfectly well as long as list has at least one element.

If it has 0 elements, you get a syntax error, which is weird if you're used to other programming languages that would allow this empty list case.

So, my question is: what's the best way to prevent this error from happening?

Initially, we did this:

```
def exists(element: String, list: List[String]): Boolean =
  if (list.nonEmpty) {
    SQL("select {element} in {list} as result")
      .on('element -> element, 'list -> list)
      .as(SqlParser.bool("result").single)
  } else {
    false
  }
```

This works perfectly well, and has the added advantage that it doesn't hit the database at all.

Unfortunately, we don't remember to do this every time, and it seems that 1-2 times a month we're fixing an issue related to this.

An alternate solution we came up with was to use a `NonEmptyList` class instead of a standard `List`.  This class must have at least one element. This works excellent, but again, people have not been diligent with always using this class.

So I'm wondering if there's an approach I'm missing that prevent this type of error better?

Comment: SQL indeed gives you a syntax error if you use an empty list in an `in` clause. The wrapper just faithfully translates your data to SQL for you. I'd go with `NonEmptyList` that makes things explicit, and try to enforce its use via type system.

Comment: Just add some dummy string to the list to avoid it: `'list -> list :: "foobar"`

Comment: If you are happy to share more of your code/design here or on a gist we can help you further with a good design as described in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is an encapsulation problem: the Anorm API is like an open flame and people can burn themselves. If you rely just on people to take precautions, someone will get burnt.

The solution is to *restrict* the access to the Anorm API to a *limited module/package/area* of your code:

- Anorm API will be private and accessible only from very few places, where it is going to be easy to perform the necessary controls. This part of the code will expose an API
- Every other part of the code will need to go through that API, effectively using Anorm in the "safe" way

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've already found a way to resolve this problem - you have an `exists()` function which handles an empty list cleanly.  The problem is that people are writing their own `exists()` functions which don't do that.

You need to make sure that your function is accessible as a utility function, so that you can reuse it whenever you need to, rather than having to rewrite the function.